# SVG fill transition takes longer on some paths than others

Tags: html, css, svg, svelte, sveltekit

The issue I've run into is that I want to transition all paths in an SVG when I hover. The code looks like this:

```html
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g>
    <path d="M3.5 3.5H10.5V10.5H3.5V13.5Z" />
    <path d="M3.5 13.5H10.5V20.5H3.5V13.5Z" />
    <path d="M13.5 3.5H20.5V10.5H13.5V3.5Z" />
    <path d="M13.5 13.5H20.5V20.5H13.5V13.5Z" />
  </g>
  <path
    d="M3.5 3.5V2.75C3.08579 2.75 2.75 3.08579 2.75 3.5H3.5ZM10.5 3.5H11.25C11.25 3.08579 10.9142 2.75 10.5 2.75V3.5ZM10.5 10.5V11.25C10.9142 11.25 11.25 10.9142 11.25 10.5H10.5ZM3.5 10.5H2.75C2.75 10.9142 3.08579 11.25 3.5 11.25V10.5ZM3.5 13.5V12.75C3.08579 12.75 2.75 13.0858 2.75 13.5H3.5ZM10.5 13.5H11.25C11.25 13.0858 10.9142 12.75 10.5 12.75V13.5ZM10.5 20.5V21.25C10.9142 21.25 11.25 20.9142 11.25 20.5H10.5ZM3.5 20.5H2.75C2.75 20.9142 3.08579 21.25 3.5 21.25V20.5ZM13.5 3.5V2.75C13.0858 2.75 12.75 3.08579 12.75 3.5H13.5ZM20.5 3.5H21.25C21.25 3.08579 20.9142 2.75 20.5 2.75V3.5ZM20.5 10.5V11.25C20.9142 11.25 21.25 10.9142 21.25 10.5H20.5ZM13.5 10.5H12.75C12.75 10.9142 13.0858 11.25 13.5 11.25V10.5ZM13.5 13.5V12.75C13.0858 12.75 12.75 13.0858 12.75 13.5H13.5ZM20.5 13.5H21.25C21.25 13.0858 20.9142 12.75 20.5 12.75V13.5ZM20.5 20.5V21.25C20.9142 21.25 21.25 20.9142 21.25 20.5H20.5ZM13.5 20.5H12.75C12.75 20.9142 13.0858 21.25 13.5 21.25V20.5ZM3.5 4.25H10.5V2.75H3.5V4.25ZM9.75 3.5V10.5H11.25V3.5H9.75ZM10.5 9.75H3.5V11.25H10.5V9.75ZM4.25 10.5V3.5H2.75V10.5H4.25ZM3.5 14.25H10.5V12.75H3.5V14.25ZM9.75 13.5V20.5H11.25V13.5H9.75ZM10.5 19.75H3.5V21.25H10.5V19.75ZM4.25 20.5V13.5H2.75V20.5H4.25ZM13.5 4.25H20.5V2.75H13.5V4.25ZM19.75 3.5V10.5H21.25V3.5H19.75ZM20.5 9.75H13.5V11.25H20.5V9.75ZM14.25 10.5V3.5H12.75V10.5H14.25ZM13.5 14.25H20.5V12.75H13.5V14.25ZM19.75 13.5V20.5H21.25V13.5H19.75ZM20.5 19.75H13.5V21.25H20.5V19.75ZM14.25 20.5V13.5H12.75V20.5H14.25Z"
  />
</svg>
```

```css
.container :global(svg *) {
  fill: var(--default-color);
  transition: fill var(--hover-transition) !important;
  transition-delay: 0s !important;
}
```

*I'm using Svelte, that's why I'm using the `:global`.*

The issue is that the last path transitions correctly, but the paths inside the group are delayed by a little bit of time.

Does anyone know why this is happening, and if there is a way to fix it?

### Partial solution

Apparently removing the `<g>` helps. I still don't know why, but it seems to be working.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a Repl https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.51.0 ?